# How do I delete all pandas dataframe created by my python code

Tags: python, r, pandas

I'm using python 3.x.I would like to delete all pandas dataframe created by my python code. I know there is an option

```
del df
```

to delete dataFrame df. But I'm looking something similar to R command

```
rm(list=ls())
```

to remove all available dataframe created by my code.
Can you please suggest?

Comment: Does [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32247643/how-to-delete-multiple-pandas-python-dataframes-from-memory-to-save-ram) answer?

Comment: Please change the tags. this is an R question and not a python

Comment: @gtomer I'm asking for python & I need something similar to R,I guess only python experts can able to answer this, not the R expert

Comment: @AbbasEbadian, no it's not helping. I'm looking for some wildcard entry,not to mention the dataframe name. I tried garbage collection one. But after running that also I can able to run head() with my dataframe name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not as straightforward in Python as it is in R. The best and safest option is to manually `del` each dataframe by name (as well as any other references to the object, e.g. if they are also in a list). However, if this isn't an option, you can iterate through all available variables, check if they are an instance of a `pandas` Dataframe, and then delete them.

If your goal is to free memory, you should manually run garbage collection after references to the objects have been deleted.

The following works for me:

```py
import gc
import pandas as pd

for i in dir():
    if isinstance(globals()[i], pd.DataFrame):
        del globals()[i]

gc.collect()
```